# Current User to Dynamically Join/Leave a Team

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simple feature to implement: clicking on a big button called "Join This Team" allows the currently signed in user to--gasp--join the aforementioned team.

So, here's what I got:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
#devise code  
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

Important question here: it's key that a user can join more than one team. Is using a join table the right approach here? Without one, correct me if I'm wrong, a user will be stuck to only a single team, right?

So, I got a simple button in teams#show

```
<%= link_to '#', :class => 'jointeam', :data => {:id =>  @team.id} do %>
  <div class='ui button'>Join This Team</div>
<% end %>
```

Now, upon clicking this button, I want the user to be added to this team. I have some JS that's incomplete:

```
$('.jointeam').on('click', function(e){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    e.preventDefault;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/teams/" + id,
      data: {_method:"PUT", }
    });
  });
```

So, I'm thinking a POST request with a method "PUT" with jQuery. Here's where I'm stuck. Since I used a Join-table called memberships, what's the right way to implement this feature?  Do I need a memberships controller? Can I have a method in my Team's controller that allows the current_user to associate to the team in question? Do I need to write a custom method? How does it tie to the jQuery ajax request to be syntactically correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [custom RESTful action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) to teams by editing the `team` resource in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :team do
  post 'join', on: :member
end
```

this will allow URLs like `/teams/<team ID>/join`

you can then create a `join` method in the `TeamController` the basics of which would be:

```
def join
  team = Team.find(params[:id])
  membership = Membership.new(team: team, user: current_user)
  current_user.memberships << membership
end
```